# Indefinite Integral similar to a Gaussian

Tags: integration

I would like to do the following integral:
$$
\int_0^t \frac{1}{(2\pi (w^2+4D^2(t-t')^2))^{(3/2)}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2+(z-vt')^2}{2(w^2+4D^2(t-t'))}\right)dt',
$$
where w,D,t,x,y are all real valued. I have looked at some standard tables of integrals for exponentials and Gaussians. I have also tried putting the integral into Mathematica in its current form and with a change of variables, setting $\tau = w^2+4D^2(t-t')^2$ and integrating with respect to $\tau$. So far I haven't found a solution. Would people here recommend numerical integration or is there an analytical solution I have missed?

Comment: To make the integral easier to understand, you can set $u=2D(t-t')$ and pull constants out of the integral, leaving you with $\int_0^{2Dt} (1+u^2)^{-3/2} \exp(au+b+c/u)\,du$ for some constants $a,b,c$. Related to Bessel functions maybe?